# How do I modify a playlist while watching videos in that playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

In the old YouTube, if I'm watching a video from my playlist, I could delete and rearrange videos in that playlist using the bar at the bottom of the page.

With the new YouTube layout, how do I delete and rearrange videos in a playlist like in the old YouTube? Or is this even possible anymore?

Answer (score 1):

> In the old YouTube, if I'm watching a video from my playlist, I could delete

YouTube new additions allow you to Delete videos (for non-autogenerated playlist and unless they [have been deleted already](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51742/43673)).

[image]

> and rearrange videos in that playlist using the bar at the bottom of the page

This functionality is still lost in the playlist (or at least I wasn't able to "drag" videos around)

Answer (score 0):

Visit the playlist you want to edit (in the URL form of `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=[SOMETHING]`). There is a button called "Edit playlist", which after clicking it brings you to a page where you can move your videos around and also remove videos from your playlist.