# How to remove [Deleted Video]'s from the current playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

YouTube recently changed some functions across all their services (the most notable, comments). And added the option to remove videos from currently watched playlists:

[image: Remove from playlist]

PERFECT! FANTASTIC! TERRIFIC! **Now, I also want to remove videos that were for X or Y reason deleted:**

[image: Deleted Video]

**But I can't.** I press the button, refresh the page and the entry persists.

BTW, [this is suboptimal](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42790/43673) as tracking them down is very painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to visit the Youtube playlist and click on "Edit playlist". Using the playlist editor, you would then be able to remove that video (along with other videos if you desire) from the playlist.

Removing videos from the playlist while playing it does not work, period.

Comment: I recommend you to visit youtube again. The update rolled out couple days ago. And yes, I'm able to delete videos from the playlist, see my screenshots. Specifically, the little text at the upper right corner, you will be able to see it if you hover the cursor in the entries of the (non-generated) playlists.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to deleted videos. You can't just delete them via the places where you made the screenshot on. You need to actually visit the playlist page and edit it to remove it.

Comment: Ah, OK. What a bummer.