# How to remove [Deleted Video] from Liked Videos list?

Tags: youtube, facebook-like, youtube-playlist

This question is similar to [How to remove [Deleted video]'s from the current playlist?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51742/how-to-remove-deleted-videos-from-the-current-playlist), but I am looking at the "Liked videos" playlist, which does not have an "Edit playlist" button.

Using YouTube on Desktop browser.

Comment: I just want to unlike a deleted video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening your **Liked videos** playlist, you can hover over the video that you want to remove and click the **X** that appears in the top-right corner of the video link. (This is located on top of the time of the video).

For example:

[image: Remove Video(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfMrD.png)]

NOTE: There is no confirmation for the video to be removed so ensure you are removing the correct video before clicking the **X**.

Comment: This no longer works, deleted videos just no longer appear in the playlist. They only contribute to the total count, e.g. in my case, it says "950 videos", but the last index is 946.

Answer (score 1):

December 2020 update: It is now possible to remove a deleted video from your Liked Videos list using the normal method!

[Previous comment: I came across the same issue. Apparently, it is currently not possible to remove your "like" from videos which have been deleted or gone private (from desktop or mobile). The usual way to do it to go to your "Liked videos" list, then click on the three dots and select "Removed [sic] from Liked videos". Deleted videos still appear there, even after clicking the remove botton. Not only that, but when going to myactivity-> Other Google activity-> View likes and dislikes on YouTube - nothing appears there. It would make sense to allow users to at least remove their likes from any video and for any reason, even if it's no longer accessible.]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your liked videos and post the following code at the end of the URL:  `&advanced_settings=1&disable_polymer=1`
2. This will open the advanced playlist and allow you to delete the video.
3. Refresh your playlist and the video(s) should be gone.

Comment: This no longer works, the old design has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers work anymore, here is a less convenient one:

1. https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp
   With this, you can run a download simulation of the liked videos playlist and print e.g. video title, ID or whatever as a reference (if you want, not necessary) and see the videos for which it prints errors like these:

   - `ERROR: [youtube] [ABCabc123-_]: Video unavailable. The uploader has not made this video available in your country`
   - `ERROR: [youtube] [ABCabc123-_]: Video unavailable. This video is private`

   Here is an example command:
   `yt-dlp -o "%(playlist_index|0001)04i_%(uploader).31s_-_%(title).63s_%(id)s.%(ext)s" --print filename https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL`
2. Optional: https://takeout.google.com
   Select "My activity"→"YouTube". You can open the resulting file in an editor, search for the ID and copy the video title, if there is one. But for private videos, it will just be the URL instead, in which case you can copy that (or just use the ID).
3. Version 1, for videos that are blocked in your country, where step 2 gives you a title: You can simply open the page and undo the like there.
   Version 2, for private and deleted videos, where step 2 gives you a URL: https://myactivity.google.com/page?page=youtube_likes
   Here you can see and manage all of your liked videos. After scrolling all the way down, you can use browser search with the URL (or just ID) to find the video. The X icon removes it, but it takes a while, sometimes multiple minutes, until the change is applied on YouTube.
   Technically you can try version 1 for every video and do version 2 for each where that didn't work, then you don't need step 2. But you can't do version 2 rightaway, because browser search doesn't help with country-blocked videos, because there the page shows the title instead. You could probably also use some browser tools to search in the page source, but I didn't try that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're referring to YouTube on a firestick then you can't remove deleted liked videos however.
Simply access your liked videos on your YouTube app on your phone. Then click the [ ... ] on top right and select remove from liked videos.